# Select certain record within response from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a call to ActiveRecord in my controller as so:

```
@configurations = EmailConfiguration.where(customer_id: '1', email_template: '1')
```

This will return all `EmailConfigurations` that have the correct parameters. Each record has a `field_id` and a `the_value`. I want to display the value in the view:

`@configurations.where(field_id: 1).the_value`

What do I need to add to the view to select a certain record within the collection that is returned by the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use select for a quick filter on arrays

```
@configurations.select {|c| c.field_id == 1}
```

that will return all collections with field_id = 1. If you know there is only one, you could chain it for a direct output:

```
@configurations.select {|c| c.field_id == 1}.first.the_value
```

Comment: You can replace `select...first` by `find`

Comment: "You can replace select...first by find" you can do this but it would result in a N + 1 Query I think since @configurations was already one call to the DB.  I am pretty sure find will be another call which is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
@configurations.where(field_id: 1)
```

returns a collection of objects(array) even if there is only one result. If you would like to show only one you can do as suggested above:

```
@configurations.select {|c| c.field_id == 1}.first.the_value
```

If you want to show all of the "the_values" you can do

```
field_1_configs = @configurations.select do |c| c.field_id == 1
end

field_1_configs.map{|config| config.the_value }
```